# How to accurately count 1 second within my logic update?

Tags: android, timer, realtime

I have the following method:

```
long time = system.nanoTime();

public void count(){

    if (System.nanoTime() > (time+1000000000)){

        //Output something or perform action here
        Log.v("timer","One second passed");

        //Reset for next second-count
        time = system.nanoTime();
    }

}
```

This should output to the console every 1 second.  It's close, but it seems not quite perfect.

If I time this with an actual stop watch (or with the same code running on another device), over time, it becomes slightly 'off'.  Not by much, but it's off.  After a minute, it's about 1/4 of a second off, the longer it is left, the larger the discrepancy.

The above method is called from within my **updateLogic()** method which is called aprox 60 times per second from my main game loop.

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't count **extactly** 1 second or why it's becoming out of snyc over time?  How can I get a perfectly accurate timer that will run exactly the same on all devices?

Comment: time += 1000000000; instead of time = system.nanoTime(); else you are skipping a few milliseconds each time.

Comment: It looks like you're making a fixed time-step update loop. While this is generally a good idea getting it right is quite hard. Please see this article: http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, your Log statement is taking up a few milliseconds, so what your code is actually doing looks sorta like this from a time perspective:

|---------1 sec------|-Log-|---------1 sec------|

As Mr. Beast said, you should use time += 1000000000;, not time = System.nanoTime();

Comment: Besides the time it takes to log, it is also possible that your game gets switched out by the OS for a while, if done at the wrong time (anywhere after the if but before the `time = nanoTime()` bit) it'll be off even more.

Comment: This.  Thanks, I thought it would be something like time being skipped somewhere but I just couldn't figure out where or how it was happening - thanks also to @Mr. Beast for the initial comment